# Desempenho em menus dinâmicos

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Estou montando uma aplicação cakephp e mysql, e gostaria de exibir alguns menus e itens dinamicamente pelo banco de dados.

Exemplificando melhor: Exibir ultimas atualizações, últimas inserções no banco de dados, menu com categorias cadastradas no sistema, etc.

O que ocorre:

-Usuário acessa a home, sistema requisita menus ao banco.

-Usuário entra em algum link, e o sistema requisita novamente ao banco de dados.

Entendo que desta forma, a cada get no site, ele irá no banco de dados novamente, buscar estas informações para renderizar os menus.

Dúvida:

- Existe alguma forma de ajustar para que o sistema crie apenas uma requisição no banco de dados no acesso do usuário, não sobrecarregando o banco com selects a cada link dentro do site?
- Alterar estas requisições para ajax seria uma boa solução?
- O CacheHelper do Cakephp consegue auxiliar nisto de alguma forma?

Comment: Por que, esses acessos ao banco estão causando lentidão? E sim, cache com os mecanismos do Cake pode ser uma boa solução.

Comment: Na verdade não está rodando ainda, mas na minha modelagem, percebi que a cada get isso aconteceria, requisitaria novamente os menus e conteúdos para o banco. Isto é uma prática normal?

Comment: Eu acho isso comum, mas meu foco é outro: não se preocupe com problemas de performance que ainda não existem, ou seja, não perca tempo com otimizações prematuras.

Comment: Eu não conheço de Cake mas eu pensaria em fazer assim: Criar um tabela autorreferenciada, faria um único select, montaria o menu

Comment: Esta solução me atendeu nesta e em outra pergunta:
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21154/passar-vari%C3%A1veis-do-appcontroller-para-elements-no-cakephp

Answer (score 2):

**Única requisição do banco de dados**

A forma mais simples de se fazer isso em php é carregar os menus de outra forma, por exemplo: guardar o array de menus em um arquivo serializado em json, toda vez que o site é carregado você lê somente este arquivo, caso este arquivo não exista você faz um select do banco e o cria.
funções úteis: `json_encode(), json_decode, file_put_contents(), file_get_contents()`.

A performance aumenta muito e caso você queira modificar o menu, basta mudar o banco e apagar o arquivo.

**Requisições em Ajax**

Você também pode carregar o menu em ajax e manter o select persistente a cada requisição do banco, isto não aumenta a velocidade final de resultado porém fará com que a página carregue mais rápido embora o menu possa ter um atraso de carregamento.

São apenas dicas, mas resumindo: sim você pode deixar mais rápido.

> "Só faça uma pesquisa no banco de dados quando realmente for necessário, use cache e indexação sempre que possível"

Comment: Pensei nisto também, configurando um cronjob para apagar o json periodicamente.

Comment: aproveitando o comentário do nosso amigo @bfavaretto, esse mesmo fluxo é a implementação do cache do cake php, você pode achar funções de cache prontas nele, o que simplifica ainda mais este processo.