# Passar variáveis do AppController para elements no Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

É possível passar variáveis originadas de callback's do AppController através do método `set` para elements do layout no CakePHP?

Comment: sim sim, da mesma forma que você passaria uma variável de qualquer outro *controller* para as *viwe* e *elements*. A diferença é que uma variável do `AppController` fica disponível à todas as *views* e *elements* do sistema.

Comment: Se eu criar um método dentro do appController e chamá-lo através da callback beforeRender ele tentará exibir uma view?

Comment: Descobri como, existe um método chamado RequestAction que pode solicitar informações de qualquer controle e também passar parâmetros..

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/pt/views.html#passando-variaveis-em-um-element

Comment: Tem isso também, assim que concluir poste sua resposta

Answer (score 1):

Pesquisando um pouco mais, encontrei uma forma de resolver:

A função `requestAction()` permite a `views` e inclusive `elements` do cakephp requisitarem informações de qualquer `controller/action` que você definir, no verdadeiro estilo MVC.

Basta declarar uma action no `Controller` específico:

```
class PostsController extends AppController {
    // ...
    public function index() {
        $posts = $this->paginate();
        if ($this->request->is('requested')) {   //Se for requisição de outra view/element:
            return $posts;
        } else {  //Senão envia para a view padrão
            $this->set('posts', $posts);
        }
    }
}
```

Então você chama a função dentro de outra view ou neste caso, um element:

**helpbox.ctp**

```
<h2>Últimos posts</h2>
<?php $posts = $this->requestAction('posts/index'); ?> <!--Passa a Action como parâmetro -->
<?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
    <ol>
        <li><?php echo $post['Post']['title']; ?></li>
    </ol>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Bônus:** Cacheando o element para diminuir as requisições no Banco:

Ao chamar o `element` dentro de alguma `view` ou no `layout`, utilize o argumento `cache`:

```
echo $this->element('helpbox', array(), array('cache' => true));
```

Assim, posso chamar qualquer `action` declarada como `public` em qualquer `controller`, de qualquer `view`, sem a necessidade de poluir meu `AppController`.

Referências:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/pt/views.html#passando-variaveis-em-um-element

Answer (score 0):

Porém já vi vários usuários comentando que não é uma boa prática utilizar "requestAction", e até mesmo ele vai ser descontinuado na versão 3 do cake, mas se você quer apenas setar uma variável global que pode ser acessada em outras áreas, poderia fazer dessa forma:

```
class AppController extends Controller 
{
    function beforeFilter()
    {
        $visivelElements = ClassRegistry::init('Configuration')->find('all');
        $this->set('visivelElements', $visivelElements);
    }
}
```

Caso fosse visível apenas em determinado controller só fazer uma verificação, algo do tipo:

```
class AppController extends Controller 
{
    function beforeFilter()
    {
        if ($this->name == 'Home') {
            $visivelElements = ClassRegistry::init('Configuration')->find('all');
            $this->set('visivelElements', $visivelElements);
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Ví alguns comentando sobre isto, porém vi o próprio Mark Story do core team voltando atrás após testar detalhadamente.